# Grabbing all matches in between two columns

Tags: awk, append, match

I have two files that I want to compare their `1st columns` and append the `2nd column` of `file2.txt` to the end of `file1.txt` only if there is a match:

```
file1.txt
NC_000008.10    1264       5646      G_synym=E4566
NC_000008.10    1264       5646      G=AGO2
NC_000008.10    5584       5646      G=AGO2
NC_000008.10    5218       5410      G=AGO2
NC_000008.10    2911       3031      G=AGO2
NC_000008.10    2552       2733      G=AGO2
NC_000008.10    0473       0609      G=AGO2
NC_000008.10    9494       9628      G=AGO2
NC_000008.10    8584       8671      G=AGO2
NC_000008.10    7188       7335      G=AGO2


file2.txt
NC_000001.10    chr1
NC_000002.11    chr2
NC_000003.11    chr3
NC_000004.11    chr4
NC_000005.9     chr5
NC_000006.11    chr6
NC_000007.13    chr7
NC_000008.10    chr8
NC_000009.11    chr9
NC_000010.10    chr1
```

I am trying with the below code - which I expect it to work -:

```
awk 'NR==FNR { a[$1] = $0; next }($1) in a { print a[$1], $2 }' file1.txt file2.txt
```

which gives this output:

```
NC_000008.10    7188       7335      G=AGO2 chr8
```

It just prints one of the matches randomly.

But the expected output would be :

```
NC_000008.10    1264       5646      G_synym=E4566  chr8
NC_000008.10    1264       5646      G=AGO2  chr8
NC_000008.10    5584       5646      G=AGO2  chr8
NC_000008.10    5218       5410      G=AGO2  chr8
NC_000008.10    2911       3031      G=AGO2  chr8
NC_000008.10    2552       2733      G=AGO2  chr8
NC_000008.10    0473       0609      G=AGO2  chr8
NC_000008.10    9494       9628      G=AGO2  chr8
NC_000008.10    8584       8671      G=AGO2  chr8
NC_000008.10    7188       7335      G=AGO2  chr8
```

How can I make `awk` print all matches instead of only one?

Comment: How does appending a column to a file relate to your subject of `Grabbing all matches in between two columns`? What 2 columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this please:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}$1 in a{$(++NF)=a[$1]}1' file2.txt file1.txt
```

You should read file2 first, and then file1.

However, a little bit ambiguous in your question though, you didn't say whether `not matched` lines should print or not.
If you don't want those lines not matched, then:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}$1 in a{$(++NF)=a[$1];print}' file2.txt file1.txt
```

Another thing is, the output fields are separated with a single space. Since your input files are seemed format well, so you may wanna `-v OFS="\t"` to separate output with `TAB`.

Note if file2 could be empty, you should change `NR==FNR` to different file checking methods, like `ARGIND==1` for GNU awk, or `FILENAME=="file2.txt"` or `FILENAME==ARGV[1]` etc.

`NR==FNR` check file, this basically means the first reading file (`file2.txt` here).
`a` is the array to store 2nd line of file1.txt, using its 1st line as key.
`$1 in a` see if `$1` exists in array `a` as key, if exists means matched. (You can change to `a[$1]` if you want check the value instead. When you are sure the value won't be empty you can use them interchangeably.)
`++NF` increase field number by 1. `$NF` represent last column. So,
`$(++NF)` represents the column after `file2.txt`'s last column.
Last bare `1` is just a simple `true` there, to imply a `{print}` block.

Comment: Yeah sorry I edited my question as I only want the matched ones. For your code, it does work! Can you explain a bit if possible?

Comment: @bapors Updated. I suggest you also to read [doc](https://www.gnu.org/s/gawk/manual/gawk.html) and `man awk`.

Answer (score 2):

The code you should be using in `Awk` should have been

```
awk 'FNR == NR { hash[$1] = $2; next } $1 in hash { NF++; $NF = hash[$1] }1' file2 file1
```

The idea is on `file2` we hash out the value in first column with the one in second. As we traverse the `file1`, for matching value in hash index, we introduce a new column to store the hashed value. `NF++` basically increments the number of columns in the file by one as we have a new column introduced containing the hashed value.

To make a more formatted output of the command, make the output separator to tab `OFS="\t"` or use the column command i.e. pipe the result of `awk` to `column -t` .

Answer (score 2):

if the files are sorted in the key, the simplest is

```
$ join -a1 file1 file2 | column -t

NC_000008.10  1264  5646  G_synym=E4566  chr8
NC_000008.10  1264  5646  G=AGO2         chr8
NC_000008.10  5584  5646  G=AGO2         chr8
NC_000008.10  5218  5410  G=AGO2         chr8
NC_000008.10  2911  3031  G=AGO2         chr8
NC_000008.10  2552  2733  G=AGO2         chr8
NC_000008.10  0473  0609  G=AGO2         chr8
NC_000008.10  9494  9628  G=AGO2         chr8
NC_000008.10  8584  8671  G=AGO2         chr8
NC_000008.10  7188  7335  G=AGO2         chr8
```

`column -t` for pretty formatting only. `a1` will print unmatched records from first file.